# How to pass text box value in export plugin?

Tags: grails, groovy, export, parameter-passing

I am able to generate & download pdf using export plugin in grails. Now, I want to pass parameters to export plugin tag,

```
<export:formats formats="['excel', 'pdf']" params ="parameters to be passed here"/>
```

I have one text box & now I want to pass that text box value into that export tag.

Simply, I want to write some text in the text box & capture entered text box value in my export tag.

Can somebody please tell me how to do that? I am new in grails. Thank you.

Comment: has this to happen at once / on the same page or is this input on a page/request before?

Comment: It happens when I click on button provided by export plugin